# Please any one can explain the detail of any kind we use #include and #Exclude Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

define both include and exclude and also example.
why we use include and exclude in MVc. where we use

Answer (score 0):

We use include and exclude in model binding. These features provide more control and security in the binding process for us. Let me explain with one example.

We have a model like this:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
}
```

By default MVC bind all of these fields from your view to your controller. But we don't want to bind AddedDate, because we want to add data to this field in the controller. So with excluding feature, we can tell the MVC that don't bind automatically AddedDate.

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude = "AddedDate")] TestModel model)
```

Or in the other situation think that your boss told you that you shouldn't let the users change their Address in the edit form. One way is that you change your view and add a hidden field inside of view to keep the Address value for binding. but sometimes due to the security issues, you cannot use this approach with sensitive data like Id, password... So you can simply exclude that fields from binding.

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude = "Address")] TestModel model)
```

In the same way, Include will tell MVC which fields should be part of the binding.

I will highly recommend you to use  ViewModel when you can, instead of using Include and Exclude features.

Comment: include should be opposite of the exclude ???  for what reason we use the include and also how to use

Comment: Yes, Include is the opposite of Exclude. Sometimes your model has lots of fields. For example, your model has 20 fields. you want to exclude 2, it is easier to use EXCLUDE with 2 items instead of using INCLUDE with 18 items. Or you want to exclude 14 items, it is easier to use INCLUDE with 6 items instead of using EXCLUDE with 14 items.